# Lightning Aura Iteration ReRender

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, iteration

I am trying to rerender an iteration(wrapper) when an input field is changed although I am extremely unfamiliar with Lightning.  Everything that I've read it "it should just work", which I don't understand.  The following the my component

```
<aura:component controller="AuraDisplayTeamMembers" implements="force:appHostable">    
    <aura:attribute name="accountPVAUserID" type="Account" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'Account' }"/>
    <aura:attribute name="taskWrapper" type="AuraDisplayTeamMembers.TaskWrapper[]"/> 
    <aura:handler name="change" value="{!v.accountPVAUserID}" action="{!c.searchUser}"/>

    <force:inputField value="{!v.accountPVAUserID.PVA__c}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="taskWrapper" items="{!v.taskWrapper}" >
        <tr>
            <td><ui:outputText value="{!taskWrapper.subject}"/></td>
            <td><ui:outputText value="{!taskWrapper.ownerName}"/></td>
        </tr>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

The following component does return everything correct and what I read was by setting the `cmp.set('v.taskWrapper', returnValue);` it will tell the component to re-render which I don't fully understand right now.  I can see in the console log my object coming back through.  I looked around quite a bit and found examples but most of them are from 2015 and everything I've found I'm doing it correctly..

```
{
searchUser : function(cmp, event, page) {
    var action = cmp.get("c.searchForUser");

    var myAttribute = cmp.get("v.accountPVAUserID.PVA__c");
    action.setParams({ "objectID" : myAttribute });

    var str = JSON.stringify(myAttribute);
    str = JSON.stringify(myAttribute, null, 4); // (Optional) beautiful indented output.
    console.log(str); // Logs output to dev tools console.
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) 
    {
        var state = response.getState();
        console.log('The response.getReturnValue() ' + response.getReturnValue());

        if (state === "SUCCESS") 
        {
            console.log('Im successful');
            var returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
            cmp.set('v.taskWrapper', returnValue);
        }
    });

    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
}
```

I'm going to post my controller code also, I believe I may be returning the wrong attribute, although I'm not clear on how to get the return value from `searchFromUser`

```
@AuraEnabled
public static List<TaskWrapper> searchForUser(String objectID) 
{

    List<TaskWrapper> result = new List<TaskWrapper>();
    System.debug('objectID ' + objectID);
    List<Task> openTasksByObjectID = [SELECT ID, Subject, OwnerID, Description, Owner.Name FROM Task WHERE OwnerID =: objectID];
    System.debug('openTasksByObjectID ' + openTasksByObjectID);
    for(Integer i = 0, j = openTasksByObjectID.size(); i < j; i++)
    {
        TaskWrapper tw = new TaskWrapper();
        tw.taskID =  openTasksByObjectID[i].ID;
        tw.subject = openTasksByObjectID[i].Subject;
        tw.ownerID = openTasksByObjectID[i].OwnerID;
        tw.description = openTasksByObjectID[i].Description;
        tw.ownerName = openTasksByObjectID[i].Owner.Name;

        result.add(tw);
    }

    System.debug('result ' + result);
    return result;
}


public class TaskWrapper
{
    public TaskWrapper(){}
    public ID taskID {get;set;}
    public String subject {get;set;}
    public String ownerID {get;set;}
    public String description {get;set;}
    public String ownerName {get;set;}
}
```

I'm not seeing any errors in the console, is there anything else I can do to debug?

[image]

Comment: I've [moved this discussion to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62800/discussion-on-question-by-ericssh-lightning-aura-iteration-rerender).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Great question!  You need to AuraEnable the properties in the wrapper class.

Comment: I was looking at this question and wondering if it is the change handler that is causing issue, great observation JRiffe. It only strikes to me now that you answered, all the wrapper variables need to be auraenabled